# Compose ReactRouter `onEnter` functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React Router doesn't seem to allow any built-in way or friendly hook for a custom helper to compose multiple check functions for `<Route onEnter />`. This would be akin to sequencing MiddleWare in other backend router frameworks.

Given a couple of `onEnter` test functions:

```
function checkA(nextState, replaceState) { // Checks one thing }

function checkB(nextState, replaceState) { // Checks one thing }
```

I'd like to be able to use one, the other, or both in sequence. Ideally, if one the first one triggered a redirect or something, the subsequent ones wouldn't be called.

Currently using RR 1.0.3.

Comment: why not just `if (checkA) { ...do something..} else {checkB}`

Comment: The `onEnter` functions we have are more along the lines of checking whether a visitor is logged in or not, and redirecting them as appropriate if they aren't in the desired auth state. The immediate problem I'm having is wanting to combine the one we have to require logged in state (redirect if not) AND check if the user is a certain type of user and I would prefer to be able to compose those functions (a la middleware patterns) rather than create a one-off function that combines the two.